# HTML Horizontal Scrolling Navbar with Sub Menus

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar

I have an intranet page that has a large navbar that causes the sub menus to display off the screen if the user has a small monitor. My idea was to have the navbar scroll but when I use overflow in the CSS a vertical scroll bar appears when the sub menus open. I want the sub menus to display OUTSIDE of the div that contains the navbar. I'm open for all ideas including reorganizing my page if I have to.

Sample HTML is:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
             <div class="scrollmenu">
                  <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#" id="" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Text</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="#" id="" role="button" data-toggle=""></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
                                            <li class="menu-item">
                                                <a id="" class="pdf" href="#"></a>
                                                <a id="" class="pdf" href="#"></a>
                                                <a id="" class="pdf" href="#"></a>
                                                <a id="" class="pdf" href="#"></a>
                                                <a id="" class="pdf" href="#"></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                   </li>
                </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS I'm using is (I found this CSS on W3schools.com):

```
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 50%;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    /*color: white;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that in order to get the scroll bar I have to use the overflow: auto setting in the CSS. But when I do that it causes the sub menus to appear in the same div which causes a vertical scroll bar to appear when a sub menu is displayed. Without the overflow setting the sub menus display outside of the div which is the desired behavior; but, of course, the scroll bars do not appear.

Help please.

FYI, I'm getting ready go home for the weekend and will followup with this on Monday.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use media queries?

Comment: Good idea but wouldn't I run across the same problem unless I completely re wrote the navbar for the smaller screens?

Comment: Are you making mobile friendly intranet page? If not then how much smaller screens are you anticipating for this?

Comment: No, not mobile friendly. We have a large plant with a lot of different sized screens, the smallest is probably 15".

Comment: using `overflow-y:hidden` and `overflow-x:scroll` should do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling nav bar is not a good design for a nav bar with sub menus. We decided to change the nav bar to an Accordion style of navigation.